# TAB key to navigate only in modal

Tags: razor, modal-dialog

Necessary to make the TAB key navigate only in modal , an example is Twitter that when modal message is open or otherwise, can not surf the screen behind through the TAB , anyone have any idea how this is done ?

Answer (score 0):

Use tabIndex = "-1" property like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1">
```

I hope it's help